# Visual Studio Code disable ctrl+click / go to definition / single click navigation

Tags: visual-studio-code

Has anyone figured out how one can **disable** the Visual Studio Code Feature that when I press ctrl + click left, that the editor navigates to the definition or opens the preview?

Since ages I am using ctrl+click to select a word to later replace it with clipboard value. . When i want to navigate to definition I press F12

The only text editor settings related I see are "Go to location commands" and "Definition Link opens in Peek". As well in the keyboard binding i can't find any ctrl+click binding.

Comment: Even when I open an editor without intellisense, Ctrl+Click doesn't select a word, double-click does. You could have some luck with `"editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd"`, which binds "go to definition" to Alt, and makes Ctrl create several cursors (which could be just as bad, but I can't test since I can't reproduce the selection method in the first place).

Comment: The "normal" Visual Studio does. Try it on a property for excample. (but you have to disable "Enable mosue click to perform Go to Definition") . It's just so much less clicking, because copying code and replacing words is something we do a lot coding, at least me. In the end it is a lot less stress for the tendons in the hand for me). I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately changing the multi cursor modifier does not enable to select a word on ctrl+click. It just selects all the same words on ctrl+double click.

Comment: unfortunately not. it is the same question, without a working answer as well. one thing is to prevent go to definition. a second thing is to select the word on ctrl click.